PhpMyAdmin not working after Ubuntu upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04
I see there is already a question very similar to mine, but with a slightly different issue. I hope this will not break any rules.
I have a web server running a LEMP stack where I upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS. Everything works fine except that PhpMyAdmin is no longer working. I reinstalled the PhpMyAdmin package and it went without issues or warnings but it still does not work.
I did check nginx, PHP, Mariadb and they are all running. The only one not started is Apache2 as can be seen as the output of sudo systemctl status apache2.service -l --no-pager.
× apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-05-21 18:36:48 UTC; 1h 17min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 35426 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 9ms

May 21 18:36:48 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 21 18:36:48 apachectl[35429]: apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.4.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
May 21 18:36:48 apachectl[35426]: Action 'start' failed.
May 21 18:36:48 apachectl[35426]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 21 18:36:48 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 21 18:36:48 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 21 18:36:48 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

Next, commands journalctl -u apache2.service and sudo apachectl configtest basically gave me the same error again:
apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.4.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf looks OK to me: IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load.
Then, line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.4.load: is a Simlink, and I noticed there were only the ones for 7.4 so I added the ones for 8.1 to no avail:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Jun 12  2021 negotiation.load -> ../mods-available/negotiation.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jun 12  2021 php7.4.conf -> ../mods-available/php7.4.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jun 12  2021 php7.4.load -> ../mods-available/php7.4.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 May 21 14:19 php8.1.conf -> /etc/apache2/mods-available/php8.1.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 May 21 14:20 php8.1.load -> /etc/apache2/mods-available/php8.1.load

Finally, I realized that the file /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so does not exist on my server, only /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.1.so.
So, the question is how do I fix this?
Any input would be greatly appreciated.

There are two ways to fix this: configure Apache to use PHP 8.1 or install PHP 7.4.
Configure Apache to use PHP 8.1
You Apache server is trying to load the libphp7.4 module and you don't have that. You can fix it by disabling this module and enabling PHP 8.1:
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enmod php8.1
sudo service apache2 restart

Install PHP 7.4
To install PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu 22.04, you need to add the ppa:ondrej/php repository, because php7.4 package is not in the official repos.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart

